# Removal of duplicate dates and their records and keep only last values intable

Tags: mysql

```
+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| date       | riverbasin1 | riverbasin2 | riverbasin3 |
+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 2014122500 | undefined   | undefined   | undefined   |
| 2015121300 | 0           | 0           | 0           |
| 2015121400 | 1           | 0           | 0           |
| 2015121500 | 0           | 0           | 0           |
| 2015121600 | 0           | 0           | 0           |
| 2015121700 | 0           | 0           | 0           |
| 2015121800 | 0           | 1           | 0           |
| 2015121900 | undefined   | undefined   | undefined   |
| 2015122000 | 0           | 0           | 0           |
| 2015122100 | 0           | 5           | 6           |
| 2015122200 | 0           | 0           | 0           |
| 2015122300 | 0           | 0           | 0           |
| 2015122300 | 0           | 0           | 1           |
| 2015122400 | 0           | 1           | 1           |
| 2015122400 | 0           | 2           | 1           |
| 2015122400 | 0           | 2           | 0           |
| 2015122500 | undefined   | undefined   | undefined   |
| 2015122600 | 0           | 0           | 0           |
| 2015122700 | 1           | 1           | 0           |
| 2015122900 | undefined   | undefined   | undefined   |
+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

There are some duplicate dates in the MySQL table like `2014122400` and `2015122300` and their corresponding records in `riverbasin` values

I want to keep only the last record corresponding to last duplicate date and delete other duplicate date and their values.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design.

Comment: What do you mean by "last"?

Comment: Do you have an ID field in your table?